# Where IN concat with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a clause in which I create a concatenation between two fields of my table in DB2.

Where inMunicipio is an arrangement of municipalities concatenated with department.
['08001', '08137', '08141']

In a normal query it would be like this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   SALUD.SF_VISITAS SV        
WHERE SV.DPTO || SV.MUNICIPIO IN(${inMunicipio.toString()})
```

This way works perfect, however I have not been able to perform the same query in sequelize. I am trying this way;

```
let whereMunicipios = sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("concat", Sequelize.col("DPTO"), 
Sequelize.col("MUNICIPIO")), {in: inMunicipio})

whereFilter = {...whereFilter, ...whereMunicipios}    
const resultado = await Visitas.findAll({
   attributes: camposVisita,
   where : whereFilter
})
```

I would appreciate your help or any guidance. Thank you.